# is we need to pay and return to site successfully to get paypal order confirmation email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, paypal

we are not getting order confirmation email if customer placed an order through paypal.but we get invoice and shipment mails.

we set `Sale : Payment Action` in paypal configuration.

so once we create the order, along with the order email [its not going to customer] i want to send invoice mail also to customer. i think this [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/auto-invoice-by-plumrocket-inc.html) will send invoice only once order **status become complete**.

if we use [SMTP extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html) will it work for us ?

is there any thing else we need to do ?

**Edit**

also I want to know is Email will send only if we pay money and succesfully return to site ? If we just click on "place order" & redirect to paypal page, will it not send email ?

```
2016-06-13T20:15:10+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Paypal_UnavailableException' with message 'Empty response.' in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php:166
Stack trace:
#0 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php(116): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->_postBack(Object(Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl))
#1 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/IpnController.php(43): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->processIpnRequest(Array, Object(Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl))
#2 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Paypal_IpnController->indexAction()
#3 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#4 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/site/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/site/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Comment: If I choose other payment method then mails were sent ??

Comment: @murtuza yes, for all other payment method , order confirmation mail will send immediately.

Comment: Have you configure the cron.sh file in your cpanel or crontab

Comment: @murtuza yes, cron is working. will it be a cron job is reason for this ? because for other payment methods we are getting email.

Comment: Might be possible if mail were added to queue programmatically  then cron job may have issue

Comment: @murtuza i wanted to know is Email will send only if we pay money and succesfully return to site ? If we just click on "place order" & redirect to paypal page, will it not send email ?

Comment: Yes If you complete the process then only E-mail will sent

Comment: okay, i am trying to pay using sandbox account with demo credit cards. but paypal payment page is not

accepting any of the credit cards. if you have any working test credit card for paypal, please tell me.

Comment: Right now I don't have any sandbox account for paypal

Comment: @murtuza no problem , i will try to get and let you know. thanks.

Comment: ok and If its working then tell me I will post answer

Comment: check the working answer below, let me know if it is working or not. It is perfectly working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Concepts

> we are not getting order confirmation email if customer placed an order through paypal.but we get invoice and shipment mails.

This clarifies one thing: that your email sending mechanism (likely the Magento cron) is working correctly in general.

> if we use SMTP extension will it work for us ?

Whether you implement this extension or not, it will not affect whether your PayPal order emails work. This module is designed to sit in the background and take the regular email send jobs from the core Magento mail module and do its own thing with them. You will not notice a difference in regular Magento use from installing it, other than an email log table in Magento admin which contains a history of your sent emails.

If you *have* installed this extension, you could use that email log in Magento admin to check what has been sent. You can access it via `System -> Tools -> SMTP Pro - Email Log`.

> also I want to know is Email will send only if we pay money and succesfully return to site ? If we just click on "place order" & redirect to paypal page, will it not send email ?

Emails are sent when certain status changes occur on various models in Magento. Order emails are sent when an order reaches the processing status, which means it has been invoiced and paid (payment method has been charged [`capture()` method]). Invoice emails are sent when the order's invoice is created (normally/often when the order is created as well). Shipment emails are created when a shipment is created for an order, etc...

**Yes** - the email will send only if you've completed the PayPal transaction and successfully returned to your Magento site (and Magento has successfully registered that payment against the order and saved it).

If you just click on "place order" & redirect to PayPal page, it **will not** trigger any emails to be sent. Your order doesn't exist at this point, it is simply a quote waiting to be converted to an order when the customer returns from PayPal.

### The code

If you [take a look at `Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::place()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php#L569) as an example, you will see the following conditions apply to when Magento will send (queue) a new order email. This method is triggered when customers return from PayPal ([the `returnAction` in `Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php#L173) sends them here via `->placeOrderAction()` then `$this->_checkout->place()`):

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
switch ($order->getState()) {
    // even after placement paypal can disallow to authorize/capture, but will wait until bank transfers money
    case Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT:
        // TODO
        break;
    // regular placement, when everything is ok
    case Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING:
    case Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE:
    case Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW:
        $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
        break;
}
```

Essentially the email will be sent (queued) if the new order's state is either "processing", "complete" or "payment_review" - have you checked the affected PayPal orders to see what their status is? You say you can ship them, so I assume that they're "processing".

The one exception as you can see above is when the state of the new order is "pending payment". The comment from the Magento developers explains it, but it can happen in a delayed payment situation. I would suggest that this is not very common.

Of course, that switch statement is specific and doesn't contain a `default` case (side note: this breaks the Zend style guidelines, but so does a lot of the core Magento code!). This means that if the order state is not any of the ones mentioned, the order will also not be sent (queued).

---

### Where to from here?

I'd suggest you do the following:

- Get a PayPal sandbox account set up in your development environment so you can test it yourself!
- Inspect the status of new PayPal orders as they come in. Look at the status of the orders. Look at the history of the order to see if anything seems out of the ordinary. Try changing the email on one of the orders to yours and triggering the order email to be re-sent manually from the order view screen in Magento admin (this will eliminate the email template itself as an issue)
- Enable PayPal logging, and inspect the API logs as the requests are made (best done in a development environment, assuming you can reproduce it)

### Notes

The comments/suggestions I've made above assume that you don't have any third-party or custom made modules getting in the way of any of the orders or payments processes in Magento. If you *do*, you should mention them!

Good luck, hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks for spoon feeding me. Complete , perFect answer. i already set up sandbox account and used some dummy credit cards, but no cards are accepting in payment gateway. if possible will try with real payment and let you know. I repeat `World need Devolopers like you`.

Comment: @user9999 It's not spoon feeding - you asked questions and the community tries their best to answer them! I'd suggest you persist with your PayPal sandbox setup. You need an accurate development environment to test things on - you shouldn't need to test things in production!

Comment: you are absolutely right. i will let you know once i done.

Comment: in both sandbox & live mode , after successull transaction, than also its showing `pening payment` as order status.

its not converting as `processing`

i followed [link1](http://www.yogisfunda.com/magento-paypal-order-status-pending-payment-setting-paypal-ipn-magento/) , [liink2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252427/magento-1-7-0-2-pending-payment-status-after-successful-payment-in-paypal)

but it did't worked for me.

Comment: please check updated question with log errors.

Comment: You have it resolved?

Comment: yes, i posted an answer, finally its working :-)

Comment: you woke up this much early ? nice :-)

Comment: It's 5pm somewhere in the world :-)

Comment: but 7 a.m there :-)

Answer (score 2):

Form Magento1.9 Order mail send via cron job .

But You can overcome using this simple free Extension, install this extension they will give you option make e-mail in queue or not

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

For Paypal Mail, complete your transaction after that you will get the mail

Comment: You are always welcome

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then please accept this answer.

Comment: sure, i will do that.

Comment: Have you get the solution or not?

Comment: Please try my answer above posted...

Comment: @murtuza sorry it didt worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to disable **SSL verification**, 
under the

```
System > Configuration > Payment methods > Paypal > Advanced settings > Enable SSL verification
```

Comment: we tried it, but it did't worked for us.

Comment: i wanted to know is Email will send only if we pay money and succesfully return to site ? If we just click on "place order" & redirect to paypal page, will it not send email ?

Comment: Try My solution

Answer (score 1):

I hope your cron working properly as magento sends  confirmation mails on cron job. see this http://www.aschroder.com/2015/01/sending-emails-by-queue-in-magento-1-9-1/ and check if your emails being stored in core_email_queue and core_email_queue_recipients.

Comment: but for other payment methods , it will send order confirmation email immediately.

Comment: Did you check your the tables if your email is being recorded in that. There ma be a chance due any errors(related to paypal,network delay etc.) magento  may not be recording in them.Are you getting any errors in system and exception logs?

Comment: which table i need to check for  email is storing or not related to paypal.

Comment: Check these tables  ' core_email_queue' and 'core_email_queue_recipients'

Comment: i will check and inform you.

Comment: i wanted to know is Email will send only if we pay money and succesfully return to site ? If we just click on "place order" & redirect to paypal page, will it not send email ?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem was some unaffected files. as some files of sites was attacked by hackers, our hosting team blocked some ports [80 or some other ports ] , after we deletd those those files, hosting team unblocked those ports , than emails are going like anything.....

Answer (score 0):

You should check your paypal configuration on your paypal account https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ 
https://lastdropofink.co.uk/tools/magento/magento-paypal-ipn/

Comment: i will check it, i wanted to know is Email will send only if we pay money and succesfully return to site ? If we just click on "place order" & redirect to paypal page, will it not send email ?

Comment: if the client didn't succesfully paid no email is sent because the ipn notification will not be sent, but if it pays even though doesn't return to your website, paypal will send the ipn notification to your magento store (if properly configured) and put the order in processing sending also the confirmation email to the client.

Comment: okay, i am trying to pay using sandbox account with demo credit cards. but paypal payment page is not

accepting any of the credit cards. if you have any working test credit card for paypal, please tell me.

Comment: yes, had same issue and don't remember if i found one but you can pay with a sandbox account as a paypal member and that works for sure and so test the notification process

Comment: i followed those links, but it did worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Latest Solution**

Please try and le me know- check my blog

http://www.anupchaudhary.com/2016/06/solved-paypal-automated-order.html

OR

You need to add some code in

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml

```
    <?php 
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    $countryCode = $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountry();
    if($countryCode!='IN')
    {
               if($order['status']=='payment_complete')
               {
                                     try
                                    {
                                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception $ex)
                                    {
                                        echo "Email Not Sent...";
                                    }
                            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
                            $email = $customer->getEmail();//End Email Sending
               }
   }?>
```

Comment: you really should not make any modification in  **app/design/frontend/base/default/**, you need to copy .phtml file into your package default theme.

Comment: Ok then copy, it will work

Comment: @AnupChaudhary sorry it didt worked for me , i added like [here](http://pasted.co/5f78f8c8)

Comment: Your country is India? I aaded the code for India

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by magento core bug.

In my exception.log file I had the following error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/mywebsite/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml on line 1
```

If you want to fix it, create your own version of file `vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.pthml` in your theme and change line:

```
<th scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($label) ?></th>
```

to:

```
<td>
    <?php 
    $x = $block->getValueAsArray($value, true); 
    if(is_array($x)){
        //print_r($x);
        foreach($x as $y){
            echo $y;
        }
    }else{
        echo $x;
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

It's a very basic fix but it worked on my case.