# send invoice email immediately when customer place an order

Tags: magento-1.9, email, paypal, invoice

i have [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116808/order-confirmation-email-not-working-for-paypal) problem,

so once we create the order, along with the order email [its not going to customer] i want to send **invoice mail** also to customer.

because we are not getting order confirmation email if we do payment through paypal standard method. but we get invoice and shipment mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Magento1.9 Order mail send via cron job .

But You can overcome using this simple free Extension, install this extension they will give you option make e-mail in queue or not

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Comment: we are not at all getting order emails only for paypal payment method, for other payment methods its working fine. we will try this and let you know.

Comment: Have you tried that extension??

Comment: i am trying that, facing some configuration issue, will check & let you know.

Answer (score 2):

**

> Here is the Latest Solution

**

Please try and le me know- check my blog

http://www.anupchaudhary.com/2016/06/solved-paypal-automated-order.html

OR

You need to add some code in

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml

```
<?php 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$countryCode = $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountry();
if($countryCode!='IN')
{
           if($order['status']=='payment_complete')
           {
                                 try
                                {
                                    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                                }
                                catch (Exception $ex)
                                {
                                    echo "Email Not Sent...";
                                }
                        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
                        $email = $customer->getEmail();//End Email Sending
           }
```

}?>